# How to develop web based voice chat app in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, chat, voip, voice

I'm looking for a set of library in C# that could help me develop a web based voice chat app. I would prefer to avoid using Flash or Silverlight if i can.

From searching the internet i found WebRTC, libjingle, FreeSwitch, Asterisk could possibly provide what i need, but none is written for C#.

Could someone point me to the right direction ?

Comment: What part of the application do you want the library to help with? The requirement for C# implies you already have the client-side of your web-based voice chat app all sewn-up; in which case, what do you want the server-side part to do? This'll help people answer IMHO.

Comment: I know it's quite trendy to avoid browser plugins, but in this area I wouldn't even consider doing it without either Flash or Silverlight.

Comment: i'm not sure why my question is closed.. perhaps it's too vaque ?

well anyway, @spender was right, i would have to do it by using flash or silverlight. Some examples that i find for it :

[Flash](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/)

[Silverlight](http://silverlightvideochat.codeplex.com/)